# API subscription key to extract and download Comtrade data/metadata

Tags: python, subscription

I am trying to access the Comtrade data using https://github.com/uncomtrade/comtradeapicall

The example code I get is:

```
comtradeapicall.bulkDownloadFinalFile(subscription_key, directory,
    typeCode='C', freqCode='M', clCode='HS',
    period='200001', reporterCode=251, decompress=True)
```

What is subscription_key and how do I use it in this API?

I have a primary key and secondary key.

Comment: this sounds like an issue to bring up with whoever is maintaining that repo.

Comment: Almsot certainly, the [API will provide some key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_key) to use in order to authenticate the request. i.e. it looks like that at least some parts of the API access to data is for registered and probably paying users. Note _UN Commtrade provides free **and premium** APIs to extract and download data/metadata_

Comment: So, you can register and check relevant API docs

Comment: It's your Comtrade subscription key. You can [get one for free](https://unstats.un.org/wiki/display/comtrade/New+Comtrade+FAQ+for+First+Time+Users#NewComtradeFAQforFirstTimeUsers-WhichsubscriptionscanIchoosefrom?). There is a preview API that doesn't require a key; these functions have names beginning with `Preview`.

Comment: BTW, I have never used this package nor Comtrade. I answered this question by Googling "Comtrade subscription key" and reading for five minutes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a credential of sorts that is provided to you by the resource provider, in this case that would be UN Comtrade. It is a safe bet that you probably need to have your application registered with UN Comtrade and through that process they will provide you the necessary credentials/access/keys to successfully make an api call.

The repo has an example file with a line declaring that subscription key variable and a comment explaining the value is obtained from UN Comtrade:

https://github.com/uncomtrade/comtradeapicall/blob/1b3ddbb1b64796671208e3b07c6f824de21f6ac5/tests/example%20calling%20functions%20-%20script.py#L7

Also this wiki seems to have more precise information regarding registering and obtaining the subscription key:

https://unstats.un.org/wiki/display/comtrade/New+Comtrade+User+Guide#NewComtradeUserGuide-ObtainingyoursubscriptionkeyforNewComtradeAPIs.

Comment: So Comtrade gave me a primary key and a secondary key. Not a subscription key explicitly as in the example. Are they different?

Comment: https://unstats.un.org/wiki/display/comtrade/New+Comtrade+User+Guide#NewComtradeUserGuide-ObtainingyoursubscriptionkeyforNewComtradeAPIs.:~:text=unlimited%20API%20calls.-,Obtaining%20your%20subscription%20key%20for%20New%20Comtrade%20APIs.,-After%20confirming%20your

Comment: According to this wiki, no.

Comment: They give you two keys so that if one leaks somehow, you can switch to the other one before invalidating the one that leaked, so that your application doesn't have any downtime. They are otherwise equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You should use primary key as subscription key. It just wrote diffrently

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).